# Delete links from string

Tags: php, hyperlink

I want to delete link from string and I have an working code, but it deletes even if you write something like: Wow you did 6.000 damage? Output is: Wow you did deleted link damage?

Can somebody help me how to delete all links, but not something like that?

Code:

```
$text = preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', '<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">deleted link</span>', $text);
```

Edit:
Explanation of links: i mean any links. Its for comments, I dont want any links there so http:// www. or only link.com
I want to remove them.

Thank you.

Comment: what is "a link"? text like: `<a href=..>...</a>`? Please, give examples of links you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose link should start with http or https, so you should replace

```
(https?://)?
```

with

```
(https?://)
```

Comment: so 6.000 could also be (in near future) correct link

Comment: Well I dont think so, but Im thinking about some sanitizin of the domain in links.

Comment: instead of \w(:\d+)? you can add list of knowing first level domains ie. (com|org|us|gb)(:\d+)? and so on.

Comment: I know there is function for sanitizing e-mails that actually compares domains, Im wontering if something like that exists fort strings and could be used in what I want to do.

Comment: you are wrong - built-in function do not recognize any domains - http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php